# Enable JSON response in Axis2

Tags: java, json, web-services, tomcat7, apache-axis

I've deployed Axis2 on a tomcat7 web server (linux machine).

To achieve this situation I copy the axis2.war into my /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps directory.
Then from my tomcat "localhostPath:8080/manager/html" I deploy the axis2.war just copied.
So browsing "localhostPath:8080/axis2/" I'm able to add a .aar service file which I wrote for axis2.

My service works well. All perfect! Service responses are in SOAP messages.

Now how can I have a JSON response from my service. I can't follow http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/json_support.html because axis2.xml is inside my axis2.war file and it is not possible to edit it.

Can someone help me? thanks a lot

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

To get responses in JSON message fromat, you need to enable the message fromatter. For that you have to edit axis2.xml.
You might need to create the war again and deploy in the tomcat.